# Can i partition my external HD into half Fedora, half Storage?

Tags: fedora, partition, external-hdd, bios

I have an 1TB external HD that i use for storage only. But it could be more useful for me if it had fedora installed. But since this is my only external HD, i still want to use it as storage to manage files.

**Will my computer recognize the right partition when i change BIOS to boot from the external drive?**

**Will the OS be able to coexist with the storage without being corrupted in some way?**

I didn't tried it by miself yet because i'm afraid i'm going to break something.

Comment: Short answer, you can install fedora and still use it as storage. Long answer requires some more things like: Which filesystem did you use on the drive (ntfs?)? Do you need windows to recognize it? Do you need it to boot on UEFI PCs?

Comment: Currently the drive has ext4 mounted. And for now i just pretend to boot the fedora on ubuntu (that boots via legacy) but use the storage on both windows and linux. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually usb disks will not have issues with multiple partitions (contrary to thumb drives) and most bioses support USB booting. Also you're suggesting a linux install, so I'll focus on a BIOS setup instead of UEFI for maximum compatibility.

You can install fedora on the ext4 partition that is already on the disk (according to the info you gave). The storage partition should be fat32 for maximum compatibility if you can deal with its limitations, otherwise use ntfs so that windows systems can still easily recognize it. Remember that there is at least a minimum risk, at any time, of data corruption on the storage and system partitions. Even if you do everything right something can go wrong.

You don't need a swap partition, even though it's recommended, so a common fedora install would set the ext4 partition as bootable and install just fine. Beware that grub may detect other OSes on the machine you're using that will appear on every other PC you connect the drive into, but obviously will not work. Also don't rely on /dev/sdX device names as they may change for each different computer you boot the drive from. Use UUIDs on the fstab file if you want to add the storage partition to it.

Just by installing fedora you might be able to mount the storage partition as if it were a separate usb disk (beware when ejecting it), but, as mentioned before, the mounting can be automated on fstab.

As long as you do not repartition the disk the risk of losing your data is neglectable, but make a full backup anyway before making any changes or installs. Also keep in mind that you will not be able to boot on ANY computer. It will fail sometimes even if usb booting is supported.